# What is the use of the locked_transfer command in the cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

What is the `locked_transfer` command used for? I'm assuming you can lock your coins for X amount of blocks before it gets sent to a destination. What are some use cases for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that function to transfer a certain amount of moneroj and ensure that the balance at the receiving end will be locked for N blocks.

Say you want to make sure you won't be tempted to sell your moneroj in the next 100 days, you can use this function to transfer moneroj to yourself with a lock time of 72,000 blocks (ca. 100 days). That way, you still own the moneroj but can't access them.

This is the reason why this function was added in the first place as can be seen in [the related commit](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1179):

> I can see people want to use it as a way to lock up monero savings and not panic sell with large swings in prices.

Comment: It should be noted that currently it will lock your change as well. Thus, to best utilize this option, send the amount you want to lock from wallet A to wallet B, then do a `locked_transfer` back to wallet A. By doing this, only that output will be locked. Thinking of it, we should probably have a `locked_sweep_all` command to fully utilize aforementioned idea (`locked_transfer` will most likely leave a small amount of XMR in wallet B).